# My Android SQLite DB query doesn't return newly inserted data until I exit my activity and restart

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm using a SQLite DB in my android application to store football players and maintain which rosters they belong to. The activity which manages these rosters has the ability to open 2 dialog windows, 1 to save the current roster to the db and 1 to load an existing roster from the db.

When a roster is saved and then the dialog to load a roster is opened, the newly saved roster is not found in my query of the existing rosters. If I exit the activity and restart it the new roster is listed and can be loaded just fine.

Here is the code which queries the DB for existing roster names

```
public String[] fetchRosterNames() {        

    String query = "SELECT "+ _ID + ", " + ROSTER_NAME + ", COUNT(" + ROSTER_NAME + ") As `NUM_PLAYERS`" +
            " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + 
            " GROUP BY " + ROSTER_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    ArrayList<String> rosterNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(!cursor.isLast()){
            cursor.moveToNext();
            rosterNames.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }
    }       
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return rosterNames.toArray(new String[rosterNames.size()]);
}
```

here is the code which inserts a roster into the DB
    public void insertRoster(String roster_name, LeagueRoster roster){

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Iterator<Player> players = roster.getFullRoster();

    while(players.hasNext()){

        Player player = players.next();         

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Log.e("MySQLiteHelper: insertRoster()", player.getName());

        values.put(PlayerStats.NAME.name(), player.getName());
        values.put(PlayerStats.POSITION.name(), player.getPosition().name());
        values.put(PlayerStats.TEAM.name(), player.getTeam().name());           
        values.put(ROSTER_NAME, roster_name);   

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    db.close();
}
```

And finally here is the code within my activity that creates the 2 different dialogs

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    switch(id) {
    case 1:         
        final MySQLiteHelper rosterData = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        final String[] items = rosterData.fetchRosterNames();
        builder.setTitle("Select the roster you would like to load");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.e("Roster Names Dialog", items[which]);
                LeagueRoster loadedRoster = rosterData.fetchRoster(items[which]);
                if(loadedRoster != null){
                    roster = loadedRoster;
                    db.setRoster(roster);
                    redrawTables();
                }
            }               
        });

        dialog = builder.create();
        break;
    case 2:
    default:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View saveRosterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saveroster_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(saveRosterView);

        final EditText nameField = (EditText)saveRosterView.findViewById(R.id.saveroster_dialog_editText);
        Button saveButton = (Button)saveRosterView.findViewById(R.id.saveroster_dialog_button);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MySQLiteHelper rosterData = new MySQLiteHelper(RosterActivity.this);
                String rosterName = nameField.getText().toString();
                rosterData.insertRoster(rosterName, roster);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }               
        });

        dialog = builder.create();
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

I would very much appreciate some help with this issue if anyone has any ideas...

Comment: The way you are fetching roster names from the Cursor is really over-complicated. You can do it much more simply. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10723771/385478

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looks much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem. It is related to how Android handles Dialogs and not SQLite. From the Android Documentation...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

> If you are using onCreateDialog(int) to manage the state of your
>   dialogs (as discussed in the previous section), then every time your
>   dialog is dismissed, the state of the Dialog object is retained by the
>   Activity. If you decide that you will no longer need this object or
>   it's important that the state is cleared, then you should call
>   removeDialog(int). This will remove >any internal references to the
>   object and if the dialog is showing, it will dismiss it.

Making sure the dialog was completely recreated every time my Load Button was pressed fixed the problem. Previously the SQLite query was not being re-run and therefore was not able to supply the dialog with new data.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Weird, but try a db.commit() after each insert?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase does not appear to have a commit() method

Comment: Nah, it's endTransaction(). I've hit this problem but not in Android, just with multiple unix processes hitting the same database. I *think* i solved it by sprinkling commits around.

Comment: I tried putting beginTransaction() before the insert and setTransactionSuccessful(), and endTransaction() after but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Too bad, out of ideas atm. But i'm sure someone that did hit your particular problem will come along soon.