# Why do Android Cursors start before the first row of results, and end after the last row?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to understand why they would start the cursor before the first position in a row and why it would end after the last position. Is there an inherit advantage to doing it this way?

For example:

> ```
> public abstract int getPosition ()
> ```
>
> Since: API Level 1
> Returns the current position of the cursor in the row set. The value is zero-based. When the row set is first returned the cursor will be at position -1, which is before the first row. After the last row is returned another call to
> next()
> will leave the cursor past the last entry, at a position of
> count().
>
> returns
> the current cursor position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a `Cursor` isn't guaranteed to be populated with rows. If you got a `Cursor` back from a database with 0 rows, the initial position being at 0 doesn't make sense since there isn't a row at position 0.

Comment: Why would this not make sense? If a cursor has 3 rows, and you've iterated through them using `while (c.moveToNext())`, it'll then be at 3, a position where there isn't a row. Why shouldn't the initial position on an empty cursor follow the same pattern? (You may be right, I'm just trying to understand the logic.)

Comment: Because the cursor would be in an indeterminate state otherwise. Position '0' would be ambiguous if it could either mean it is empty or there is a row. The iterator used underneath the cursor *can't* be at position 0, because there isn't a position 0.

In your example, the cursor won't ever show it's position as 3. It'll fail trying to move from 2 to 3, and thus stay at 2 and exit the loop.

Comment: My last point is wrong. It *does* show position 3. My only guess is to stay consistent with the logical beginning. -1 is the logical start of the cursor, and count() is the logical end of the cursor. I'm not in a position to test it, but from inspecting the source, I would guess that calling `moveToNext()` on an empty cursor would also show it's at position 0, which would be the logical end.

Comment: "Because the cursor would be in an indeterminate state otherwise. Position '0' would be ambiguous if it could either mean it is empty or there is a row." Just because the position doesn't tell you the row count doesn't mean the cursor is in an indeterminate state. Position -1 is just as ambiguous: it doesn't tell you whether the cursor is empty or there is a row.

Comment: That's not its purpose to tell you those things. It's purpose is to mark the logical start of the cursor. It's a non-position used only to indicate that the iterator has been initialized or reset.

Comment: I agree with you, it's not the purpose of the cursor position to tell you whether there is a row. That's why I don't follow "If you got a Cursor back from a database with 0 rows, the initial position being at 0 doesn't make sense since there isn't a row at position 0."

Comment: You misunderstand. I'm specifically talking about position -1, not all cursor positions. Position -1 and count() are special cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129657/discussion-between-larsh-and-jason-robinson).

Answer (score 6):

So you can do this:

```java
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(...);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    // deal with one row at a time
}
```

It's by far the neatest way to iterate over a Cursor's results (see [What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/what-is-the-neatest-way-to-iterate-over-the-results-in-an-android-cursor)), and it wouldn't work if it didn't start **before** the first row.

Comment: Sorry but that is purely incidental. I agree that using `while (c.moveToNext()) {...}` is the neatest way to do things and is the way I always do it but I don't believe that's why a `Cursor` is always positioned before the first row. As Jason says, a `Cursor` may be returned with no results and as such it must be positioned at a 'neutral' position. Further to that, it is not the business of any query engine to assume the developer wants a `Cursor` returned set to any absolute position within the row set (first, last, somewhere in between etc).

Comment: The OP asked about advantages, and I see this as advantage - and therefore a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android [`SQLiteCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) is a wrapper object to native SQLite database cursor, which is a control structure that lets you traverse records in a database.
I assume, that before calling `setPosition` or `moveToFirst` native cursor even doesn't load query results to memory to save space.

Comment: So were you suggesting that when you call `moveToFirst()` or `setPosition()`, the cursor goes ahead and loads query results (without waiting for a `getString()` or other direct data access)?