# SQLite auto increment not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, auto-increment

ok this isn't spamming and it's supposed to be simple I don't know why it's not working
this is my code:

```
gamesdatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("GamesDatabase", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
gamesdatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Games (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name
VARACHAR, NPlayers INT(1), NRounds INT(2), WinScore INT(2));");

gamesdatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO Games 
(ID, Name, NPlayers, NRounds, WinScore ) VALUES ( NULL, 'TAWLA',2,0,0 );");

gamesdatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO Games 
(ID, Name, NPlayers, NRounds, WinScore ) VALUES ( NULL, 'DOMANA',4,0,0 );");


Cursor c = gamesdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Games", null);
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
Log.d("BEZRA", String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"))));
c.moveToNext();
}
```

what's wrong with this ? the log displays 0 for all records

Comment: autoincrement works. you just have to actually use it.

Comment: The way you are looping through the Cursor values is far too complicated. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The primary key for SQLite tables is called _id. It is auto incrementing, and you should not be trying to insert values into it.

```
gamesdatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("GamesDatabase", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
gamesdatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Games (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name
VARACHAR, NPlayers INT(1), NRounds INT(2), WinScore INT(2));");

gamesdatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO Games 
(Name, NPlayers, NRounds, WinScore ) VALUES ('TAWLA',2,0,0 );");

gamesdatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO Games 
(Name, NPlayers, NRounds, WinScore ) VALUES ('DOMANA',4,0,0 );");


Cursor c = gamesdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Games", null);
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
Log.d("BEZRA", String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"))));
c.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Actually the column name doesn't need to be named "_id"

Comment: You're probably right, but you are commenting on an answer that I gave 8 years ago.

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me was renaming my create type from INT to INTEGER and it started working.

From this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id INT PRIMARY KEY, bar INT)
```

to this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar INT)
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can see 
http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-autoincrement-serial-identity-primary-key
**Example**
CRETAE_TABLE

```
  CREATE TABLE salespeople (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  commission_rate REAL NOT NULL
);
```

INSERT_DATA

```
 INSERT INTO salespeople VALUES (null, 'Fred', 'Flinstone', 10.0);
```

---OR---

```
INSERT INTO salespeople (first_name, last_name, commission_rate) VALUES ('Fred', 'Flinstone', 10.0);
```

Comment: The added insert statement helpful. I miised the null part for the id and was getting error in my code

Answer (score 2):

`c.getColumnIndex("ID")`
gets the index of the column, which ID is 0 indexed column, Name is 1 etc

you want

`c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"))`

Comment: it's like that in the code it was my fault when copying it and it's not working thanks

Comment: This answered a problem I was having with my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to tell it that the column is auto incrementing.

```sql
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
```

instead.

Comment: it didn't work but thanks anyway, the trick was in renaming ID into _id, AUTOINCREMENT is not necessary when you use integer primary key

Answer (score -1):

Because You didn't set it to auto increment. Primary key is not enough.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Games (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARACHAR, NPlayers INT(1), NRounds INT(2), WinScore INT(2));
```

Comment: I did set the AUTOINCREMENT and didn't work and then I read that primary key is more than enough

Comment: I wrote NOT enough. You need both primary key and auto increment.

Comment: @Gustek, sqlite assumes autoincrement for a field specified with PRIMARY KEY

Comment: according to sqlite http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html documentation, PK is sufficient to obtain unique ids, and usually they are monotonic (unless you set yourself some strange id)