# webSQL AUTOINCREMENT not working (Different from the one in search)

Tags: android, cordova

Learning phonegap to write a basic app for Android.  Using WebSQL for this reason, I know it's deprecated but it's just for an Android phone and no scaling so not going to bother with things like polyfills at this time.

Just trying to get auto_increment to work before I even get started on things like callback handlers, the basis for the code:

```
var db = openDatabase('test', '1.0', 'Test', 10 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(
    function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, value VARCHAR)');

    }
);

$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        alert('click');
        db.transaction(
            function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (?)', ["testValue"]);
            }
        );      
    });
});
```

Tried using things like the default keyword, but nothing seems to work.  If I add a value for the ID column it works fine.

---

**EDIT** Here's code trying it out, inserts nothing.

```
var db = openDatabase('test', '1.0', 'Test', 10 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(
    function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR)');

    }
);

$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        alert('click');
        db.transaction(
            function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (?)', ["testValue"]);
            }
        );      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR)');
```

In webSql (sqlite) PRIMARY KEY automatically increments unless you pass values. Additional information here: http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Doesn't work because the goal here is to get AUTOINCREMENT to work on INSERT.

Comment: I use it this way in my phonegap project and does autoincrement on insert. Have you tried it?

Comment: You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832401/sqlite-auto-increment-not-working

Comment: Okay it's working on it's own, just not inserting on the click event.  Interesting.

Comment: Try moving the `alert` to after the transaction and see what happens. In PG alerts can mess with things

Comment: Pulled it out entirely, just there to show that function is running.  Still no joy.

Comment: I know websql can be very picky, it was a big pain to setup my app. try escaping all of the labels of things ( `\`test\`` and `\`value\``) value I believe is a reserved word. I know I have had that issue many times. If that doesn't work, rename value to something like itemValue.

Comment: Got it working, had to be syntax but not sure where.  Thanks much for the time.