# Android while !c.isAfterLast() loop not being entered

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**Question** Following tutorial, trying to put some simple string into a database every time I press a button. I believe that the "usernames" are being entered into the database, while debugging it doesn't do anything funny. My problem is when I want to call `databaseToString()`, I set a Cursor to the first entry. But subsequently it doesn't even enter `while(!c.isAfterLast())`. What is going on? I want it `dbString` to pretty much be equal to the database in plaintext, but that's not happening. Thanks

**Attempts**

- Checked around SO/Google/API guide/thenewboston source code
- Tried viewing my SQLite database, but I'm not sure how to do that so I couldn't
- If you comment out databaseToString then I guess it runs, but it just sits there.
- It also crashes when I set `Text.setText(dbString);` but that's completely unrelated

**LogCat** It doesn't crash, if needed I'll post.

**SearchActivity.Java** INSERT GETS CALLED WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED

```
public class SearchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText Input;
    TextView Text;
    Database dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Input);
        dbHandler = new Database(this, null, null, 1);
        // printDatabase();

    }

    // Add a user to database
    public void insert(View view) {
        Users user = new Users(Input.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addUser(user);
        printDatabase();
    }


    public void printDatabase() {
        // dbString is returning null
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        //Technically it starts to crash right at this line
        Text.setText(dbString);
        Input.setText("");
    }    
}
```

**Users.java**

```
public class Users {
    private int _id;
    private String _username;

    public Users() {

    }

    public Users(String username){
        this._username = username;
    }

    public String get_username() {
        return _username;
    }

    public void set_username(String username) {
        this._username = username;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
}
```

**Database.java** aka Handler. Look at `databaseToString()` and the while loop isn't entered whatsoever for some reason.

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Version number to upgrade database version
    // each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change
    // the version number
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";


    public Database(Context context, String DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // There must be a ',' in between every column definition
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_USERS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add a new row to the db
    public void addUser(Users user){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, user.get_username());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String databaseToString() {
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE 1";

        // Cursor point to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // Move to the first row in your results
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("username")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("username"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the return value of insert and see what it's returning.  If it is returning -1 that means it was not successful.  `long retVal = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);`

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks for that awesome tip it says I have retVal = 14. At least I know it's working now, thanks

Comment: Sure.  Next thing to check is the return value of getCount() on the Cursor after the call to rawQuery:  `int count = c.getCount()`

Comment: @DanielNugent count = 15, I pressed it a lot earlier. thanks

Comment: Are you calling `findViewById()` somewhere for `Text`?

Comment: @DanielNugent Yeah, SearchActivity.java line 28;;; EDIT: oh by the way i kept checking c.isAfterLast and now it returns false??? Anyway now it enters the loop

Comment: You might have an infinite loop since you're not progressing the Cursor.  Add `c.moveToNext();` after  `dbString += "\n";`  Also, put your `Text =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);` in `onCreate()` to make sure you don't get the NullPointerException.

Comment: @DanielNugent Hey man I was out but thanks so much it's working as perfectly as I expect. If you write up c.moveToNext() I'll accept it. Kudos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixing the NullPointerException:**

First, to fix the NullPointerException, initialize `Text` in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Input);
    Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text); //added
    dbHandler = new Database(this, null, null, 1);
    // printDatabase();

}
```

**Debugging tips:**

In order to make sure that insertion into the database is successful, capture the return value of `insert()`:

```
long retVal = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
```

Then, to verify that data is present in the Cursor, get the count of the Cursor:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int count = c.getCount(); //added
```

**Solution:**

Finally, there are a few things to add here.  First, you need to progress the Cursor in order to not have an infinite loop.  Also, you should check the return value of `moveToFirst()`, and do nothing if it returns false.
Lastly, you should close the Cursor when you're done with it, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

```
public String databaseToString() {
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE 1";

    // Cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    // Move to the first row in your results
    //check that moveToFirst returns true
    if (c.moveToFirst()){

      while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("username")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("username"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext(); //added
      }

    }
    c.close(); //added
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps you:

> The simplest way is this:
>
> ```
> while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> The cursor starts **before** the first result row, so on the first
>   iteration this moves to the first result **if it exists**. If the
>   cursor is empty, or the last row has already been processed, then the
>   loop exits neatly.

[What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10723771/3854270)

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't enter the loop