# How can I reference a cursor

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I wish to use a CursorLoader in my application but I don't want to use the returned cursor with a SimpleCursorAdapter. I just want to get a reference of the cursor returned from onLoadFinished()

Here is some code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>

    {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle arg)

    {

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }


 @Override


public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 

      {

      return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,PROJECTION, select, null, COLNAME );


   }

 @Override

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) 

    {
    // rather than swap the cursor with SimpleCursorAdapter reference, I wish to return the cursor so I can reference it


     }

    }
```

Any ideas how this can be done

Comment: you can save a reference if you want, and iterate through it to use its data, it's not necessary to use a cursoradapter, what is the problem you have?

Comment: @ILovemyPoncho  If u can please, help me with the codes of how to save the reference of the cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create class member:

```
private Cursor mCursor;

...

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mCursor = data;
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mCursor = null;
}
```

from de [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader%3CD%3E)): onLoaderReset - Called when a previously created loader is being reset, and thus making its data unavailable. The application should at this point remove any references it has to the Loader's data.

And [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor) you can see ways to iterate a cursor.