# how to get every row from SQLite from a function that returns only one row at a time

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a `SQLite` DB which contains N rows, I need to retrieve every row by knowing the number of rows in the DB, what I've tried is this:

```
public CategoriesItem returnCategory(int index){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mRow= db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " LIMIT 0, " + index, null);
        if (null!=mRow) {
            mRow.moveToNext();
            item.auto_id = Integer.toString(mRow.getInt(mRow.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            item.title = mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex(KEY_CATEGORY_NAME));
            item.subTitle = mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex(KEY_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION));
        }

        return item;
    }
```

The problem is that it returns only the first row, everytime even if the index is not 1.
What is wrong with the query? How can I get a single row values by knowing the amount of rows in the DB?

Comment: You don't have a WHERE in your SQL... What does `"LIMIT 0, " + index` do?

Comment: @cricket_007 I just have the amount of rows in the DB, then I can the returnCategory function N times in order to retrieve every single row of the db, but I can't understand how to get one by one

Comment: It is not answer for your question, but I think it's worth to add here - **Always** close `Cursor` when you finish your operations. Wrap your code in `try`-`catch`-`finally` and place `mRow.close();` in `finally` block.

Comment: If you call this function N times, you will be running the same query N times and only retrieving the top result. You need to **move the cursor** `index` times.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've closed the cursor and I've edited the query, i've used limit 1 and offset index, now it seems to work

Comment: To get the total number of records (rows) within a table: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;". To get all records: "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE recordIDFieldName <> 0;"

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work, I'll do some test but this should be the solution:

```
Cursor mRow= db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + index, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is iterate over the `Cursor`, you can then use the data from every single row. 
[What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor)