# Fetching data from sqlite database returning no records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

A row is inserted successfully in database. I export `sqlite` database file and it shows me the record. Now i am trying to fetch that record from database. Database only has 1 record.

```
 String containerData = "";

        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("select "+ " * " + " from "+ TABLE_NAME, null);

 if(cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();    
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            containerData= cursor.getString(0);
           }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
```

I have tried to use db.query(), also tried to remove while loop and used following.

```
  containerData= cursor.getString(0);
```

but this gives me following error message

> Method threw 'android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   exception.

There are total 5 columns in my table.

Comment: Firstly i would recommend switching from raw sql , and to a more faster and friendlier approach ORM, realm for android is no-sql and is much faster and easier to maintain

Comment: the easiest way is `Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(...); if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { do { /*do something with cursor*/  } while(cursor.moveToNext());} cursor.close()`  there is no need for null check from rawQuery

Comment: And i would not recomend ORM as Cursors has lower memory footprint using fx CursorAdapter is much faster then loading all objects into POJO and using CustomAdapter

Comment: @Selvin @Remario : WIll this be more efficient if i use this `db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME}, null,null,null,null,null);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor)

Comment: it will be better: 1.it's not load unnecesery columns 2. you are sure that colum with index 0 is your column

Comment: @Selvin : Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following code:

```
 String containerData = "";

 SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("select "+ " * " + " from "+ TABLE_NAME, null);

 if(cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();    

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        containerData= cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        Log.d("ShowData->", containerData);
    }
 }

 cursor.close();
 db.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You check cursor only for null, you need to check if there is any values in that cursor too:

```
if (cursor != null && !cursor.isAfterLast()){
...
}
```

Comment: !cursor.isAfterLast() is returning true, and when i export the file, it shows the record in the table