# Android SmsManager send message to multiple recipient from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, smsmanager

I'm newbie to android please help me in my problem. I want to send message to multiple numbers. The numbers are saved in SQLite database. I want to send the message to all the numbers saved in database table.

Here's my code so far it only send sms to only one number in my database. It only send to the first number in my table.

```
private void sendSMS(String message) {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
    }else{
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from recipients_tbl", null);
        if(res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
            String num = res.getString(1);
            sms.sendTextMessage(num, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is only sending it to the first number is you are not looping trough your result. In order for it to work you will need to write your code like this:

```
if(res != null){
    for(res.moveToFirst(); !res.isAfterLast(); res.moveToNext())
    {
        String num = res.getString(1);
        sms.sendTextMessage(num, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is iterate through the Cursor e.g.

```
private void sendSMS(String message) {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
    }else{
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from recipients_tbl", null);
        while (res.moveToNext()) {  //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
            String num = res.getString(1);
            sms.sendTextMessage(num, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }
        res.close();
    }
}
```

- Note checking a Cursor, returned from an SQLiteDatabase method, such as query or rawQuery, is useless as a valid Cursor will be returned. If a Cursor has no rows then it will be empty the (getCount method will return 0). As such `if(res.moveToFirst()) .....` is better than `if(res != null && res.moveToFirst()) .....`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, change:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
```

to:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
```

Because you are not writing to database.

Then, what you have to do is, iterate through each and every row:

```
while(res.moveToNext())
{
    String num = res.getString(1);
    sms.sendTextMessage(num, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
res.close();
```

You know, Cursor is pointing at the first row and you have to get that cursor to next row by `moveToNext()`. And lastly donot forget to close the `Cursor`.

FYK: [What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor)

Comment: `getReabableDatabase` does not protect/stop write. In fact `getReababledatabase` will in most cases get a writable database. It will only get a read only database if there is an problem and the database can only be opened in read mode [getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase%28%29)

Comment: @Uiv yeah, thats true.