# How to fetch data from multiple columns in sqlite android using cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I want to fetch data from multiple rows and columns using curser using this below code

```
  Cursor getallrecords(){

    SQLiteDatabase dbb = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;

    if (dbb != null){
        Log.d("cursor","not null");
      
        cursor = dbb.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);

        }else{
        Log.d("cursor","null");
    }

    return cursor;
    }
```

On logcat it shows the cursor is not empty and returns data. But when I try to set that data which cursor carries on ArrayList using the below code.

```
  void read(){
    Cursor cursor = save_barcode.getallrecords();

    if (cursor.getCount() != 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            url.add(cursor.getString(1));
            type.add(cursor.getString(2));
            date_and_time.add(cursor.getString(3));
        }
    }

    if (!url.isEmpty()){
        Log.d("message","not null");
    }else {
        Log.d("url","null");
    }

    if (!type.isEmpty()){
        Log.d("message","not null");
    }else {
        Log.d("type","null");
    }
    if (!date_and_time.isEmpty()){
        Log.d("message","not null");
    }else {
        Log.d("date","null");
    }
}
```

Then in logcat it shows URL,date_and_time, type all of these three are empty. So if anyone knows how to fetch data from multiple rows and column using cursor then help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem with your code is that you are using `moveToFirst()` and after that `moveToNext()`, so it is certain that you lose the 1st row.
If all you have in the table is just 1 row then the lists will be empty.
No need to check `getCount()`, so remove `if` and no need for `moveToFirst()`.

Change to this:

```
void read(){
    Cursor cursor = save_barcode.getallrecords();
    if (cursor == null) return; 
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        url.add(cursor.getString(1));
        type.add(cursor.getString(2));
        date_and_time.add(cursor.getString(3));
    }
    cursor.close();

   ...................
}
```

Comment: Bro my apk still crash when i try to set data on recycle view. In logcat it shows  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

Comment: @Akshit this is not because of the code in my answer. Your app crashes when you call `setText()`.

Comment: Because settext method does not get any value this means obviously there is something we r missing in fetching data.

Comment: @Akshit no this is not the problem. The problem is that the TextView on which you call setText is null. This is what *null object reference* means.

Comment: Look bro i use holder.getBarcodeUrl.setText(String.valueOf(url.get(position))); on my recycleview holder and the url is refering to a arraylist which geting from read method by using cunstructor.

Comment: @Akshit this is another problem for which you must ask a new question where you explain what the problem is. Questions are not asked in the comments section.

Comment: Thanks, bro my problem is solved. The fault was in the adapter class.

Comment: @Akshit fine if it is solved and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.